# SQL Server could not parse CDATA from XML string

Tags: sql-server, xml, utf-8, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to parse XML string which has UTF-8 encoding.

```
declare @xml varchar(max) = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Message>
    <![CDATA[’]]>               
</Message>'

select cast(cast(@xml as varchar(max)) as xml)
```

Execution of this query gives me an error.

```
Msg 9420, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
XML parsing: line 3, character 11, illegal xml character
```

If I remove or replace UTF-8 encoding to UTF-16 it works great. What is the difference?

I've tried to parse this string using C# console application and it parsed XML successfully. Is it bug of SQL Server?

SQL Server version:
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4042.0 (X64) 
Mar 26 2015 21:18:04 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2  (Build 9200: )

Comment: Versions of SQL Server prior to 2016 do not recognise the UTF-8 encoding. And, apparently, the 2016 version has only some limited support - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510411.aspx for details.

Comment: I've got it. XML parsing on SQL Server fails every time when string contains some UTF-8 character inside of VARCHAR string. As long as VARCHAR is 1 byte per char encoded it cannot deal with UTF-8 characters which encoded with more than 1 byte encoded.

Answer (score 2):

That character (the right quote) is encoded here as 0x2019 which is not a valid UTF-8 character, it's UTF-16. See this helpful page about [Unicode character 0x2019](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm).

It works in .Net because .Net strings are UTF-16 strings.

EDIT: If you save your above SQL snippet as UTF-8 in SSMS it will then execute successfully.

Comment: The right quote is UTF-8 compatible character. It is encoded with three bytes: 0xE2 0x80 0x99 (e28099)

Comment: Yes, but in the text you posted it's encoded as 0x2019, which is the UTF-16 encoding for right quote.